# how can you navigate in a browser with selenium without closing it and opening it again?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, python-venv

here is my newest code for this questions. now i can get go from page to page without closing and opening the webdriver but i only get the data from the first page and then nothing. in my console i get i huge chunk of html which is normal but normally it needs to be followed by the data i scraped after the first page, i can't get anymore data

```
import scrapy
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENTS = [
   ...
]

class Alibaba3CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba3_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['http://alibaba.com/']
    search_text = "shoes"
    page_num = 1
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 8,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.0,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Alibaba3CrawlerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Initialize the Selenium WebDriver and store it in a class variable
        driver_path = GeckoDriverManager().install()
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("-headless")
        driver_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_service, options=options)

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f"https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.32521541bYkLGt&fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&keywords={self.search_text}&tab=all&&page={self.page_num}"
        headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}
        
        # Include your GitHub Personal Access Token here
        github_token = token
        
        # Set up headers with the token
        headers['Authorization'] = f'token {github_token}'

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url, 
            callback=self.parse, 
            headers=headers, 
            meta={"search_text": self.search_text,
                  "page_num": self.page_num, "github_token": github_token}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        
        for _ in range(1):
            self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            
        updated_page_source = self.browser.page_source
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(updated_page_source, 'html.parser')
        product_cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='fy23-search-card fy23-list-card m-gallery-product-item-v2 J-search-card-wrapper')

        data = []
        for card in product_cards:
            title_element = card.find('h2', class_='search-card-e-title')
            title = title_element.text if title_element else None
            price_element = card.find('div', class_='search-card-e-price-main')
            price = price_element.text if price_element else None            
            shipping_per_pair_element = card.find('div', class_="search-card-m-sale-features__item")
            shipping_per_pair = shipping_per_pair_element.text if shipping_per_pair_element else None   
            other_element = card.find('div', class_='search-card-e-popper__trigger')         
            other = other_element.text if other_element else None
            rating_element = card.find('span', class_='search-card-e-review')
            rating = rating_element.text if rating_element else None
            
            img_link_div = soup.find('div', {'class':'search-card-e-slider__wrapper'})
            
            if img_link_div:
                a_tag = img_link_div.find('a')
                href = a_tag['href'] if a_tag else None
                
                img_tag = img_link_div.find('img')
                img_src = img_tag['src'] if img_tag else None
                 
                
            data.append({
                'Title': title,
                'Price': price,
                'Rating': rating,
                'Shipping_per_pair': shipping_per_pair,
                'Other_Info': other,
                'Link' : href,
                'Image_link': img_src,
            }) 

        if data:
            yield from data

        current_page_num = response.meta["page_num"]
        if current_page_num < self.settings.get('MAX_PAGES', 100):
            next_page_num = current_page_num + 1
            next_url = f"https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.32521541bYkLGt&fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&keywords={self.search_text}&tab=all&&page={next_page_num}"
            headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}
            
            github_token = response.meta.get("github_token", "")
            headers['Authorization'] = f'token {github_token}'
            
            yield Request(
                next_url,
                callback=self.parse,
                headers=headers,
                meta={"search_text": response.meta["search_text"],
                      "page_num": next_page_num,
                      "github_token": github_token,
                }
            )
    
    def closed(self, reason):
        # Close the browser when the spider is closed
        self.browser.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, you start the driver and set it up in `__init__` then store it in a class variable, then use that variable inside the functions.

Comment: For example: `browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_service, options=options)` and everything above it in the `parse` method you move to `__init__` and change it to `self.browser = ........` then instead of `browser.get` yo do `self.browser.get`

Comment: will the line updated_page_source = browser.page_source work this way? it's the only way i can move the next page

Comment: it should, you have to change all `browser` to `self.browser` of course.

Comment: i will try that thanks!

Comment: i have the changes you have told me but i can only get the data of the first page. do you have any ides about this ?

Comment: Update the code in your question then. Or better yet, add the new code at the end.

Comment: i updated the situation!!

Comment: What if you take out the headless option and watch what's happening?

Comment: i took the headless option off and i way that in the first page bit of time before scrolling down and print the data then the browser loaded the second page and almost directly scrolled down and directly went for the third page

Comment: Well I believe your main question about "not closing and opening the webdriver" is solved, you can try to open a new question for any additional questions or problems you encounter.

Comment: that's true thank you sir!